# A Young's inequality used to bound curvature terms

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, curvature, integral-inequality

I've been having a look at the Gage and Hamilton's *The Heat Equation Shrinking Convex Plane Curves* ([here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214439902)). In particular I've been working in the **Lemma 4.4.2** and some further results where they find bounds for the higher derivatives of $\kappa$. The lemma states the following:

*If $\kappa$ and $\kappa'$ are bounded, then $\int_0^{2\pi} (\kappa'')^4$ is bounded.*

In the proof, they calculate
$${\partial\over\partial t}\int_0^{2\pi} (\kappa'')^4=-12\int_0^{2\pi} \kappa^2(\kappa'')^2(\kappa''')^2+2\kappa\kappa'(\kappa'')^3(\kappa''')+3\kappa^2\kappa'(\kappa'')^2\kappa''',$$
using that
$${\partial\kappa\over\partial t}=\kappa^2{\partial^2\kappa\over\partial\theta^2}+\kappa^3.$$
Then, for the first expresion, they use the Peter-Paul inequality $ab\leq 4a^2/\varepsilon+\varepsilon b^2$ (a version of the Young's inequality for products) to "bound the second and third terms by the first term and some additional penalty terms" to obtain
$${\partial\over\partial t}\int_0^{2\pi} (\kappa'')^4\leq \int_0^{2\pi} C_1\kappa'^2(\kappa'')^4+C_2\kappa^2\kappa'^2(\kappa'')^2.$$

The proof continues a little bit, but I'm struggling to understand the last step. I don't really get how they use the previous inequality to obtain the estimate.
Any idea or hint is more than welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I meet the same problem.I am struggling to finish the former calculation.Are the 3 terms all negative ? Or only the first term?Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of computations show up a lot in geometric analysis. The point is that you have a **negative** term

$$-12\int_0^{2\pi} \kappa^2(\kappa'')^2(\kappa''')^2$$

on the right hand side, which you want to take advantage of. So you wish to make up the term $\kappa\kappa''\kappa'''$. For the second term, write

$$2\kappa\kappa'(\kappa'')^3(\kappa''') = 2\big(\kappa\kappa''\kappa''' \big) \big(\kappa'(\kappa'')^2\big)\le \epsilon{\big(\kappa\kappa''\kappa''' \big)^2} + \frac{1}{\epsilon} (\kappa'(\kappa'')^2)^2$$

Similarly for the last term,

$$3\kappa^2\kappa'(\kappa'')^2\kappa''' = 3\big(\kappa\kappa''\kappa''' \big) \big(\kappa \kappa'\kappa''\big) \le \frac{3}{2} \bigg( \delta\big(\kappa\kappa''\kappa''' \big)^2 + \frac{1}{\delta} \big(\kappa \kappa'\kappa''\big)^2\bigg)$$

Then get $\epsilon, \delta$ small so that $-12$ kills off the terms.