# Inequality used to bound curvature terms

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, plane-curves, mean-curvature-flows

I've been poring over the article: Gage and Hamilton's *The Heat Equation Shrinking Convex Plane Curves*
[(here)](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214439902). In **Lemma 4.4.2** , it's supposed to find bounds for the higher derivatives of *k*.In the part of proof,it can be obtained that  $$\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}\int_0^{2\pi } {{{({\rm{k}}'')}^4}}  =  - 12\int_0^{2\pi } {{k^2}} {(k'')^2}{(k''')^2} + 2kk'{(k'')^3}(k''') + 3{k^2}k'{(k'')^2}k''',$$ where uses the integration by parts(the second step) and evolution equation $$\frac{{\partial k}}{{\partial t}} = {k^2}\frac{{{\partial ^2}k}}{{\partial {\theta ^2}}} + {k^3}.$$and commutes$\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}} and \frac{\partial }{{\partial \theta }}$( at the first step).

Then, the authors use a corollary of mean inequality [here, by @user99914](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1824258/833136).Here , my questions come up:

1.In first expression above, are the three terms of ***RHS*** all negative? Or only the first term? (I think it's impossible).If all the three term are negative, after using the mean inequality twice and then    add them up,  **Shouldn't the inequality sign change?** I think I am in a false sense,could you please provide some detailed explanations?

2.The same problem appears in **Lemma 4.4.3**. This time I fall into disorder.

3.Next,using the assumption that $$\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}\int_0^{2\pi } {{{(k'')}^4}}  \le \int_0^{2\pi } {{C_1}} k{'^2}{(k'')^4} + {C_2}{k^2}k{'^2}{(k'')^2}$$ , then how to obtain $$
\int_0^{2\pi } {{{(k'')}^2}}  \le {(\int_0^{2\pi } {{{(k'')}^4}} )^{\frac{1}{2}}}\sqrt {2\pi }
$$

Related question:[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1824238/833136)

I can't solve the questions above for a while, may be the solutions are obvious... Any ideas will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1, 2: we know only the first term
$$ - 12\int_0^{2\pi } k^2(k'')^2(k''')^2$$
is negative. We are just using
$$ 2ab \le \epsilon a^2 + b^2 /\epsilon,$$
and this holds even when $a, b$ are negative.

3: The inequality
$$\int_0^{2\pi } {{{(k'')}^2}}  \le {\left(\int_0^{2\pi } {{{(k'')}^4}} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\sqrt {2\pi }$$
has nothing to do with the differential inequality. Just use Holder's inequality:

$$\int_0^{2\pi } (k'')^2  = \int_0^{2\pi} (k'')^2 (1) \le \sqrt{\int_0^{2\pi} (k'')^4} \sqrt{\int_0^{2\pi} 1^2 }$$

Comment: @ Arctic Char Thanks.So it seems that I make mistakes in the  computational process $$\begin{array}{l}
\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}\int_0^{2\pi } {{{(k'')}^4}}  = {\rm{4}}\int_0^{2\pi } {{{(k'')}^{\rm{3}}}({k^2}k'' + {k^3})''} \\
\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;{\rm{ = }} - 12\int_0^{2\pi } {{{(k'')}^2}(k''')} ( + 2kk'(k'') + 3{k^2}k')\\
\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; =  - 12\int_0^{2\pi } {{k^2}} {(k'')^2}{(k''')^2} + 2kk'{(k'')^3}(k''') + 3{k^2}k'{(k'')^2}k'''
\end{array}$$  What does each step use?(For example，integration by parts?， or commutability of $t$ and $\theta $?..)

Comment: 1st equality: $\partial_t$ and $\partial_\theta$ commutes and the differential equation for $k$. 2nd equality: integration by part and $(k^2 k'' + k^3)' = 2kk' (k'') + k^2k''' + 3k^2 k')$ (there's a typo, you are missing one term). 3rd equality: just caculation. @sraungJo

Comment: $\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
{\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}\int_0^{2\pi } {{{(k'')}^4}} d\theta  = {\rm{4}}\int_0^{2\pi } {{{(k'')}^{\rm{3}}}({k^2}k'' + {k^3})''d\theta }  = 4\left[ {\int_0^{2\pi } {({{(k'')}^{\rm{3}}}({k^2}k'' + {k^3})')'d\theta  - \int_0^{2\pi } {({{(k'')}^{\rm{3}}})'({k^2}k'' + {k^3})'d\theta } } } \right]\; = 4\left[ {0 - \int_0^{2\pi } {({{(k'')}^{\rm{3}}})'({k^2}k'' + {k^3})'d\theta } } \right]}\\
{{\rm{ = }} - 12\int_0^{2\pi } {\left[ {{{(k'')}^2}(k''')({k^2}k''' + 2kk'(k'') + 3{k^2}k')} \right]} d\theta }
\end{array}$  Would you please find the mistakes? @ Arctic Char

Comment: (to continue) I think I was on the right way...Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any mistake in the above calculation @sraungJo

Comment: Emm....My "negative" means there are "minus signs" in front of the 3 terms.For the last two term, a<=p+q,b<=r+s,then follows -(a+b)>=-q-p-s-r,    isn't it right? @Arctic Char

Comment: It does not matter what is the sign in front of it.... you do not know the sign of $k', k''$ and so on..... or you can just use $-2ab \le \epsilon a^2 + b^2/\epsilon$. @sraungJo

Comment: "$-2ab \le \epsilon a^2 + b^2/\epsilon$" is what I look for, and I am suddenly enlightened.Thank you again.As a beginner and a non-english-speaking student(with poor English),I am lucky to have your help.Thank you so much. @Arctic Char